# Does this Non-Hausdorff winged quadruped anatomy actually work?

Tags: anatomy, alien-geometry, wings

The design features two non-contacting 'branches', one for the wings and another for the forelegs

The ribcage is roughly avian, and exists on both branches. Attached are a pair of feline-type forelegs and shoulders on one branch, and a pair of avian wings on the other. The muscles that attach to the limbs exist only on their limb's branch, but the muscles between parts of the ribcage exist on both

They have a single skin on both branches, which covers both limbs. Each branch has an air-sac, which fills the wing skin and pectoral region in the leg branch and the leg skin in the wing branch

The creature with this anatomy is roughly the size of a Haast's eagle. It should be able to fly like a bird and walk and use its legs like a feline

Could this anatomy work as I have described?

Comment: This is one of those cases where a picture is worth thousands of words. It's not a coincidence that anatomy books are always illustrated.

Comment: Yeah we need a picture because from description, i imagine a quick squishy bundle of feathers without any survival skills. no claws yet no arms, no means to hold prey in place.

Comment: I second the other comments here. Without some sort of visual diagram, any attempt to answer has to guess at what your creature looks like, and will almost certainly guess incorrectly. That's not going to make for a very useful answer. For instance, the picture in my own mind right now looks rather like a bat, with wing tissue connecting the forelimbs and rear limbs to each other; that's incompatible with bird flight, where the legs are entirely separate from the wings.

Comment: What do you mean by "branch"? What do you mean "the ribcage exists on both branches" (the meaning is weird, usually we say that appendages and equivalents are linked to the body, not the reverse)? What is an Hausdorff quadruped? I can't find anything on it which is about biology, only [maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension)

Comment: I think we've had a conversation about non Hausdorff stuff before.

Comment: PSA: [Non-Hausdorff manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold). "[Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)" is the felicitous Englishing of Riemann's original German *Mannigfaltigkeit*, word-by-word many-fold-ness. It refers to a topological space which resembles a regular Euclidean space in an infinitesimally small neighborhood of each point, but it is not necessarily Euclidean when seen globally. A Hausdorff space is a space where any two points have disjunct neighborhoods; a non-Hausdorff space is a space where some distinct points cannot be separated.

Comment: @ IchthysKing If what AlexP provided is what you meant, first I'm sorry to have not understand your question. Then, I highly advise to add the definition into your question. When dealing with multidisciplinary topics, it's important to define which term comes from which discipline. It is even more so important when the topic isn't easy or common .

Comment: @Tortliena There is a fair overlap between here and Maths Stack Exchange. I have encountered at least one other person who understands what Hausdorff means. Unfortunately I cannot confidently count Ichthys King on that list.

Answer (score 1):

## If you want

You have an animal with the top half existing in one dimension, and the bottom half existing in another, and the middle somehow existing in both dimensions at once.

I guess to people on the leg dimension it just looks like a pair of legs and a body, and to people in the wing dimension it looks like a pair of wings attached to a floating body.

There is of course, blood flowing between the parts. So the body has a magical dimensional-converter to convert the ordinary leg blood particles to colocated wing blood particles.

This is all so far outside the realm of possibility that it works if you want it to work. You have two imaginary things connected by a third imaginary thing. Depending on the rules or how the first two things work, this creates problems. You can give the third thing whatever properties you need to fix those problems.